# Image not responding to different keys Pygame Python

Tags: python, variables, pygame

Good day. I am trying to make a ground move left and right when the opposite keys are pressed, but for some reason, the image just keeps moving to right. Here's the *reasonable* part of my code:

while not crashed and not timeOut and not Quit:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        Quit = True

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            gx_change = 2.5
        elif pygame.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            gx_change = -2.5

        if pygame.key == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                gx_change = 0

print (event)

gx += gx_change
```

As I said, it just keeps going right.

UPDATE: It is fixed

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your if statement for KEYUP is actually inside the if statement for KEYDOWN. This is the correct code:

```
while not crashed and not timeOut and not Quit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Quit = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                gx_change = 2.5
            elif pygame.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                gx_change = -2.5

        if pygame.key == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                gx_change = 0

    print (event)

    gx += gx_change
```

Comment: @ArihanSharma the change is where the indention is

Comment: Yes, thank you now I would like to upvote your answer, but it has locked my vote. Could you please consider making a *minor* edit to this?

Comment: UPDATE: It has been fixed.